# Data Learn (AWS MSK with Google Dataflow connection issue)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-kafka, google-bigquery, dataflow, aws-msk

My Google Dataflow Job is keep getting failed while creating "Kafka-Bigquery" dataflow with AWS MSK public access bootstrap server. Is there any way to solve this issue?
[image]
[image]

I tried accessing public access bootstrap server by disabling unauthenticated access and enabling IAM based access, and also updated security groups to access from anywhere. also created a topic using EC2 instance terminal by accessing through private connection string.
In GCP, I created a dataflow using Kafka-Bigquery template and passed public-access-bootstrap-connection-string, and topic created in EC2 also passed bigquery table id.
Expectation: Job creates successfully and table is populated based on kafka message sent to msk server.

Can I connect AWS MSK (Kafka) with Google Dataflow (Kafka-Bigquery) Job (as consumer)?

Comment: If you use `kcat -L`  inside cloud shell, for example, are those addresses resolvable outside of AWS?